# Error in parsing response in retrofit android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I am trying to use Retrofit in android for the first time. I have managed to have a successful call but i am struck in the below case:
There are two types of responses i am getting:
**Response-1: Success response**

```
{
    "results": {
        "message": {
            "en": 301000897837,
            "ete": "PM",
            "vto": "PM",
            "er": false
        },
        "status": "Success",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

**Response-2: Error response**

```
{
    "results": {
        "message": "Invalid",
        "status": "No Content",
        "code": 204
    }
}
```

I have created two POJO classes namely `EwResponse.class` and `EwResults.class`

```
public class EwayBillResponse {

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private EwayBillResults results;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public EwayBillResponse() {
    }
```

public class EwResults {

```
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public EwResults() {
}
```

I could make a call and analyse response the error case of error response.
I know i am not using `message POJO` in success response in `success_response` but i am clueless on how to use two types of response calls in a api call of retrofit.

This is the following error i am getting in case of success response:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 24 path $.results.message
```

This is the first time i am using retrofit. So please help me.

Thanks in advance
**EDIT:**
**Request call code:**

```
Call<EwResponse> ewcall=apiService.generateEB(EwResponse);
                            ewcall.enqueue(new Callback<EwResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<EwResponse> call, @NonNull Response<EwResponse> response) {
                                    if(response.isSuccessful()&&response.body().getResults().getCode()==200){
                                        Gson gson=new Gson();
                                        EwMessage EwMessage=gson.fromJson(response.body().getResults().getMessage(),EwMessage.class);
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+response.body().getResults().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<EwResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Log.e("ERROR",""+t.getMessage());
                                }

                            });
```

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for creating your pojo class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to handle the case for string response and Object response dynamically , Use this

```
    public class Results {

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Object message;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;

public Object getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(Object message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
this.code = code;
}

}
```

Inside the `results` object you have field called `message` which can be an `object/string`

So inside retrofit onResponse method,

```
if (response.getMessage() instanceof Message)
        {
        handleObjectResponse();
     }
    else 
        {
        handleStringResponse();
     }
```

Message.java

```
public class Message {

@SerializedName("en")
@Expose
private Integer en;
@SerializedName("ete")
@Expose
private String ete;
@SerializedName("vto")
@Expose
private String vto;
@SerializedName("er")
@Expose
private Boolean er;

public Integer getEn() {
return en;
}

public void setEn(Integer en) {
this.en = en;
}

public String getEte() {
return ete;
}

public void setEte(String ete) {
this.ete = ete;
}

public String getVto() {
return vto;
}

public void setVto(String vto) {
this.vto = vto;
}

public Boolean getEr() {
return er;
}

public void setEr(Boolean er) {
this.er = er;
}

}
```